# strict inclusion implies the strict inclusion of the closure?

Tags: general-topology

How to prove:
If $A\subsetneq B$ are irreducible closed sets in a subset $Y$ of a topological space $X$, then $\overline{A}\subsetneq \overline{B}$.

Comment: But, we do not know if $Y$ is open or closed.

Comment: $A$ is an irreducible closed set of $Y$ means that any two non-empty open subsets of $A$ (induced subtopology)  have non-empty intersection.

Comment: Well, $\overline{A}\cap Y = A$.

Comment: Indeed, irreducibility does not make a difference here.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is closed in $Y$, so $A=Y\cap\operatorname{cl}_XA$. Let $U=X\setminus\operatorname{cl}_XA$; then since $B\subseteq Y$ we have

$$B\setminus A=B\setminus(Y\cap\operatorname{cl}_XA)=B\setminus\operatorname{cl}_XA=B\cap U\;,$$

so no point of $B\setminus A$ is in $\operatorname{cl}_XA$, and therefore $\operatorname{cl}_XA\subsetneqq\operatorname{cl}_XB$. Note that irreducibility isn’t needed here.